# Twisted and starpy error (python)

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using this:

```
from twisted.web.client import getPage
df = getPage(url) # there is some url
```

I'm getting the following error. Please can anyone guide me on this

```
ERROR:twsited:Unhandled error in Deferred:
ERROR:twsited:Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/starpy/manager.py", line 123, in lineReceived
    self.dispatchIncoming() # does dispatch and clears cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/starpy/manager.py", line 200, in dispatchIncoming
    callback( message )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 243, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 312, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 328, in _runCallbacks
    self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/starpy/manager.py", line 298, in errorUnlessResponse
    raise error.AMICommandFailure( message )
starpy.error.AMICommandFailure: {'message': 'Channel not specified', 'response': 'Error', 'actionid': 'askme-158811948-5'}
```

I'm not sure this error is due to getPage() method because even when i've commented this it still give me the same error. Can anyone help. I can't figure out the reason for the error and where it is generated

Comment: twisted.web.client.getPage isn't a starpy API, but your error is coming out of starpy, so I think there's some other code that's actually triggering your problem.

Comment: i'm just calling this function getPage(url) it is returning a deferred object. Actually I read in a book that it returns the contents of from this url, but instead it is showing this error.

Comment: I'm not sure this error is due to getPage() method because even when i've commented this it still give me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted is not complete. The error is not due to getPage.
From the stack trace clues, this uses AMIProtocol (line receiver) .
I guess some where you have to specify your protocol channel in AMIProtocol

setVar(self, channel, variable, value)  in star.py.

This is not a twisted issue.